# Gluon CompleteableFuture Unsafe Access Denied on a Device

Tags: java, android, gluon-mobile

I initially wrote a function called `backendMethodCall` to use an old python WSGI gateway. Everything worked fine until I decided to check out gluon to develop something for android mobile devices. I used the code to successfully call a remote server when testing on my desktop, however when I used the androidInstall task to install the app onto my android device (LG G4, 6.0) and make the call, the app crashes.

I used `adb logcat > test_log` to get the following error:

```
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.testgluon, PID: 12394
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Unsafe access denied
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.<clinit>(CompletableFuture.java:3009)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.backendconnection.RESTClient.backendMethodCall(RESTClient.java:67)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.testgluon.views.SecondaryPresenter.lambda$initialize$0(SecondaryPresenter.java:29)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.testgluon.views.SecondaryPresenter$$Lambda$2.handle(Unknown Source)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3761)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3489)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2498)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
12-28 12:50:42.513 12394 12415 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEve
12-28 12:50:42.515  1244  3577 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.testgluon/javafxports.android.FXActivity
```

Method Call:

```
public static void backendMethodCall(String method, Consumer<ArrayList>callback, Consumer<String> faliure_callback, Object... arguments) {

    Consumer<String> consumer = (json) -> {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                if(json != null) {
                    ArrayList result = convertToArraylist(json);
                    callback.accept(result);
                }else {
                    if(faliure_callback != null) {
                        faliure_callback.accept(json);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };

67:   CompletableFuture<Void> backendCall = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {


        Message message = new Message(arguments);
        Client client = null;
        String result = null;

        try {
            client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            URI tempURI = getBaseUri();
            WebTarget target = client.target(tempURI);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String send = gson.toJson(message);
            System.out.println(send);
            result = target.path(method).request().post(Entity.entity(send, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), String.class);

        } catch(RuntimeException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally { if(client != null) client.close(); }

        return result;

    })
    .handle( (json, ex) -> {

        if(ex != null) {
                    System.out.println("JSON: " + json);
            System.out.println("Error");
                    System.out.println(ex);
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    })
    .thenAccept(consumer);
}
```

`build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.10'
}
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
jcenter()
maven {
    url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
}
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

dependencies {
compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.4.1'

compile group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.0.1'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-client', version: '2.17'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-json-jackson', version: '2.17'
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.2'
}

jfxmobile {
downConfig {
    version = '3.6.0'
    // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
    plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
}
android {
    manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    androidSdk = 'C:\\Users\\Steven\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}
ios {
    infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    forceLinkClasses = [
            'com.gluonhq.**.*',
            'javax.annotations.**.*',
            'javax.inject.**.*',
            'javax.json.**.*',
            'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
    ]
}
}
```

I am not sure why this is happening. My initial thought was that the code required some permission to run, but I do not see any indication of what permission that may be.

Comment: There is a similar issue already reported [here](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/8u-dev-rt/issues/10/creation-of-a-completablefuture-causes). However I've run this [project](https://github.com/macgibbon/CompletableFutureTest) perfectly fine on Android 7.1.1, with jfxmobile 1.3.10. Can you test it as well, and post your settings (`build.gradle`, Android version)?

Comment: @JoséPereda I've run the test project from my IDE and encounter no problems, however, when I run the program on my Android device (Android Version: 6.0), I get the same error as posted above. I have also provided my build.gradle file.

Comment: @Pereda I have also successfully made calls to my backend from my Android device by cutting out the CompletableFuture. However, that mean the call is made synchronously.